# Откуда hibernate берет несуществующие данные?

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть форма и таблица с данными.
Открываю нужный объект для редактирование в первый раз, естественно всё нормально. Закрываю форму. Из БД вручную удаляю строку. Открываю форму ещё раз. И откуда-то hibernate берет данные(из кэша ли) которых в БД уже нет.
Почему, если я закрываю сессию, то и данных в кэше быть не может...
Открытие формы:

```
ProductBrand productBrand = productBrandDAO.getById(
        Long.parseLong(getTblPanel().getValueRow(index).get(0)));

int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
    modalPanel.createEditingProductBrandPanel(
            new ProductTypeDAO().getAll(), productBrand),
    "Редактирование значений:", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Метод getById:

```
@Override
public ProductBrand getById(Long id) {

    Session session = null;
    ProductBrand result = null;

    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        result = (ProductBrand) session.get(ProductBrand.class, id);

    }catch (Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Ошибка I/O", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally {

        if (session != null && session.isOpen())
            session.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Как так получается? Ну от куда подгружаются те данные которых в БД уже нет? И как это запретить?
**UPD_1**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в самой проге:

```
@Override
public boolean delete(Long id) {

    Session session = null;
    boolean flag = true;

    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.delete(new ProductBrand(id));

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        flag = false;
        session.getTransaction().rollback();

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Ошибка I/O", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
    } finally {
        if (session != null && session.isOpen())
            session.close();
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: а когда вы удаляете вручную, вы делаете коммит транзакции?

Comment: покажите как вы удаляете, не из IDEA случайно ли?

Comment: @KirillStoianov upd в вопросе сделал. Не, эклипс + heidisql

Comment: 1. Как товарищ Senior Pomidor сказал, вы делаете комит? Потому что в IDEA к примеру удалить строчку не достаточно, нужно еще сделать коммит.

2. Попробуйте удалить из базы в ручную, что то типа такого: " delete from tableName where id=13; "

Comment: @KirillStoianov так, попробовал - не помогает. Но если подождать секунд 20-30(дошло до минуты), то всё нормально - выбрасывает ошибку там где нужно, нет таких данных в бд. Это с чего бы такие тайминги 0_о?

Comment: я с Hibernate не особо знаком, но если данные остаются после ручного удаления из базы, то скорее всего где то в кэше сидит. + проблема может быть в том что вы зачем то удаляете не из кода, попробуйте удалять строчку с помощью Hibernate

Comment: @KirillStoianov Да, чёрт возьми) Придумал себе проблему, пытался её криво решить - не получилось.
Собственно да, если нормально удалять с hibernate то проблемы уже нет. Спасибо)
Хотя всё равно странно, почему нужно ждать какое-то время если в ручную удаляю из БД?

Comment: Тайминг ,возможно, может быть связан с тем что Hibernate не сразу ловит изменения в самой базе данных, но это лишь предположения!)

Comment: Настройки кэша hibernate не изменяли? По умолчанию включен кэш 1го уровня, когда объекты кэшируются в пределах сессии. Но т.к. вы делаете запросы каждый раз в новой сессии, то проблема может быть в кэше 2го уровня (в рамках фабрики сессий), когда при ручном удалении из БД в кэше лежат старые данные - но этот кэш по умолчанию выключен.

Comment: А вообще, посмотрите в логах - идет ли запрос к БД при 2ом открытии.

Comment: @Nikolay да, идёт. Собственно вопрос уже решен. Как оказалось, нужно начинать и коммитить транзакцию при селекте(getById), именно так я начал получать реальные, адекватные данные. Хотя, конечно, странно.